# Is it possible to use partials with the layout option inside of a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When try I following code in a controller, the view renders *without* using the layout

```
  def xyz
    render :partial => 'platinum_home', :layout => 'platinum_layout'
  end
```

But If I do the following inside the partial

```
<% render(:layout => "platinum_layout") do %>
  blah blah blah
<% end %>
```

It works just fine, is the first example not possible using rails?

Comment: It should work just fine. What version of rails are you using? Do you have a layout macro call at the top of your controller?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller at the top add the following:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    layout "platinum_layout", :only => :xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial rendering in a controller is most commonly used together with Ajax calls that only update one or a few elements on a page without reloading. Rendering of partials from the controller makes it possible to use the same partial template in both the full-page rendering (by calling it from within the template) and when sub-page updates happen (from the controller action responding to Ajax calls). By default, the current layout is not used.

So to use current layout for your just used.

```
  def xyz
    render :partial => 'platinum_home', :layout => true
  end
```